# how to detect closed socket in PHP (FIN flag)?

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

Here is my problem:
FIN and RST packets detect correctly only when there is NO `socket_set_nonblock` option for socket-functions or `stream_set_blocking` (for fsockopen) is set to FALSE.
Is there a way in PHP to detect manually when socket closes?

Comment: Once a socket is closed, I believe it is not a resource anymore. Have you tried using `is_resource()` or `is_null()` on the descriptor ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I tested it and got a valid resource on the client side even though server has closed socket. And when client tried to write to socket it caused an error.

Comment: Try using `stream_get_status`.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? There is even no such function. Although neither `stream_get_meta_data` nor `socket_get_status` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What about using classes? you'll be sure about it's closed with destructors